# Some Questions about Flurry

Tags: android, analytics, ads, flurry, android-contextmenu

Hello I am implementing the Flurry Ads and Analytics in my application. My application has complex activity structure which includes tabhost, tabgroup, context menu, Option Menu and many other things.

While implementing I get several questions in mind and fail to get the flurry working properly.

So, My Questions are-

1. How can I check source network(appcircle,admob,InMobi etc) of recieved Ad? OR  which ad network serve current ad ?
2. How can I get the number of active sessions currently?
3. How can I test Individual ad network (appcircle, admob, InMobi etc) working properly and serves the ads successfully?
4. Does anyone have implement the flurry ads with different ad networks? If yes, can please you provide the manifest data for those network.
5. Why Context is so important for FlurryAgent (flurry messes with context)? Can't it be global (ApplicationContext) instead of Local (ActivityContext).

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to know the source of ad through the device. Flurry provides the impression reporting for all the ad networks individually for you to keep track. In order to test ad network mediation, you can change the priorities of ad networks, and check whether ads are getting received from the ad networks with the highest priority. Also, note that you can turn off AppCircle backfill on your ad space page (Publishers tab>Inventory>Ad Spaces>AppCircle Network).

For details on implementing mediation inside your code, please refer to the integration manual inside the SDK folder, or the [Support page](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/Code) .

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)